# How can I get a table in R with the mean values of t, t-1, t-2, t-3, etc. of a variable in a timeseries?

Tags: r, time-series

For instance, I want to get a table with the average of "value" for 1 day (already calculated), the last 2 days, the last 3 days, etc. and up to the last 10 days.

```
df<- data.frame(day = seq(as.Date("1910/1/1"), as.Date("1910/1/10"), "days"), value = c(1, 4, 7, 33, 2, 6, 9, 88, 5, 6))
```

Any hints?

Comment: Please provide data.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please read [ask] and give a [mre] in your question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df<- data.frame(day = seq(as.Date("1910/1/1"), as.Date("1910/1/10"), "days"), value = c(1, 4, 7, 33, 2, 6, 9, 88, 5, 6))

library(tidyverse)
library(slider)

df <- 1:9 %>%
  map(
    ~slide_dbl(df$value, ~mean(.x), .before = .x, .complete = F)
  ) %>%
  bind_cols() %>%
  bind_cols(df, .) %>%
  set_names(c("day", "value", paste0("value", 2:10)))
```