# Rolling averages for grouped data and more than one variable

Tags: r, slider

I would like to get the rolling average at time 't-1', 't-2, 't-3', etc. of two variables and grouped data. The code below works without grouping by variables `londeg` and `latdeg`, with variable `vw` and a window of 3 days.
How can I get the code running for the data grouped by `longdeg` and `latdeg`, and calculated for the variables `uw` and `vw`?

Glance at data :

```
structure(list(dateday = structure(c(18525, 18525, 18525, 18525, 
18525, 18525, 18525, 18525, 18525, 18525, 18525, 18525, 18525, 
18525, 18525, 18525, 18525, 18525, 18525, 18525), class = "Date"), 
    latdeg = c(39.875, 39.875, 39.875, 39.875, 39.875, 39.875, 
    39.875, 39.875, 39.875, 39.875, 39.875, 39.875, 39.875, 39.875, 
    39.875, 39.875, 39.875, 39.875, 39.875, 39.875), londeg = c(0.125, 
    0.375, 0.625, 0.875, 1.125, 1.375, 1.625, 1.875, 2.125, 2.375, 
    2.625, 2.875, 3.125, 3.375, 3.625, 3.875, 4.125, 4.375, 4.625, 
    4.875), uw = c(-4.0046167, -2.9436386, -1.384588, -0.0981078, 
    1.0286689, 1.91347, 2.4027817, 2.6116273, 2.7161477, 2.6292932, 
    2.5535467, 1.9434952, 1.0219297, 0.6225892, 0.40092927, 0.5625489, 
    1.1099254, 1.4549272, 1.716492, 2.1899667), vw = c(1.6297868, 
    2.7284932, 3.7426023, 3.9648964, 3.8228495, 3.5595078, 3.2727604, 
    2.994605, 2.795548, 2.652693, 1.9364153, 0.73406154, -0.4248537, 
    -1.1846231, -1.6087885, -1.7109653, -1.2042828, -0.75072134, 
    -0.56564194, -0.34468606)), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Code (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/64575069/14535832)

```
  library(tidyverse)
  library(slider)

  df <- 1:3 %>%
  map(~slide_dbl(df$vw, ~mean(.x), .before = .x, .complete = F)) %>%
  bind_cols() %>% 
  bind_cols(df, .) %>% 
  set_names(c("dateday", "latdeg", "londeg", "uw", "vw_day0", paste0("vw_day", 1:3)))
```

Lee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may do a `group_split` within the first `map`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(slider)
map(1:3, ~ df %>%
       group_split(latdeg, londeg) %>%
       map_dbl(function(x) slide_dbl(x$vw, ~ mean(.x, .before = .x,
         .complete = FALSE))))
```

Comment: Thanks! However I get an error when I apply this function to my extended dataset (> 150000 rows) the error I get is: "Error: Result 1 must be a single double, not a double vector of length 378". Any thoughts?

Comment: @Lee1010 Can you try the function on a subset of data instead of the whole data and see if that shows the error.  If the error is not present, then it could be an issue with the vector length

Answer (score 0):

I've found an alternative answer to my question, which may be a bit sluggish but works well.

```
  for(rolldays in 1:3) {
  new_col_name <- paste0("day_", rolldays)
  df <- df %>% 
    group_by(latdeg, londeg) %>% 
    mutate(!!sym(new_col_name) := zoo::rollapplyr(uw, rolldays, mean, fill = NA, na.rm = T)) %>% 
    as.data.frame()
}
```